# Websecurity.Login in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, authentication, websecurity

I'm having a problem with this code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { Id = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name) });
    }

     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel user)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(user.UserName.Trim(), user.Password.Trim(), true))
     {
         Session["UserName"] = user.UserName;

         return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
     }

     return Json(new { errorMessage = "Lietotāja vārds vai parole nav pareiza" });
}
```

UserController:

```
public ActionResult Index(int Id)
{
    return View();
}
```

WebConfig:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="/Home/Index" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

After Websecurity.login I need to redirect to **User/Index/id**. When I look on the Network, I can see this request, but the page view is old. When I hit F5 or go to **Home/Index**, I am right away redirected to **User/Index/id**.

I can do this in Javascript. I get success = true after logging in and can update the page by using

> window.location.refresh()

But I would like a better option.

Comment: A couple things.  You need to show more of your code.  I don't see a login get action etc.  In your post, you just redirect back to the login page.  You should redirect them where you want them to go once authenticated. There are numerous examples on here about how to do basic login.

Comment: I did redirect to right away User/Index, but also it doesn't work